# Reduce padding before and after figure (with sub figures)

Tags: floats, pdftex, subcaption

I have the following code to include two images in my document:

```
\begin{figure}[!ht]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{1.0\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=6.31cm]{fig1_xxx.eps}
        \caption{}
        \label{fig1}
    \end{subfigure}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{1.0\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=6.31cm]{fig2_xxx.eps}
        \caption{}
        \label{fig2}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{ABC capion: (a) XYZ and (b) PQR}
\end{figure}
```

The above code places two images vertically centered in the document. However, I find that it is producing a lot of unnecessary padding before and after the image is inserted. Can anyone suggest how to tackle this issue?

Comment: did the answer below meet your requirement?

Answer (score 1):

The code added to the MWE will all reduce padding, you can define the values as per requirement

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry} % set suitable page parameters
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{caption} % optional 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\raggedbottom
\begin{document}
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{-10pt}
\captionsetup{belowskip=0pt}
\renewcommand\floatpagefraction{.7}
\renewcommand\dblfloatpagefraction{.9} % for two column documents
\renewcommand\topfraction{.7}
\renewcommand\dbltopfraction{.9} % for two column documents
\renewcommand\bottomfraction{.7}
\renewcommand\textfraction{.1}   
\setcounter{totalnumber}{50}
\setcounter{topnumber}{50}
\setcounter{bottomnumber}{50}
\vspace{-7pt}
\begin{figure}[!ht]
    \centering\offinterlineskip
  \fbox{\begin{subfigure}[b]{.6\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[vspace=0pt, height=10\baselineskip]{example-image-a}
        \caption{}
        \label{fig1}
    \end{subfigure}}

    \centering
    \fbox{\begin{subfigure}[b]{.6\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=10\baselineskip]{example-image-b}

        \caption{}
        \label{fig2}
    \end{subfigure}}
    \caption{ABC capion: (a) XYZ and (b) PQR}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

If it meets the requirement please accept the answer

Comment: Although OP failed to provide a minimal working example, you should probably include only the necessary packages in yours...

Comment: Sir please have a look now

Comment: Much better, yes. Thanks